# Register User along with new attribute (column) value in Parse (Back4App Flutter SDK)

Tags: flutter, dart, parse-platform, parse-server, back4app

```
final user = ParseUser(username, password, email)..set('isAdmin', false);
var authResponse = await user.signUp();
```

Hi, I am using the above code to assign a boolean value "isAdmin" to the User, because I want to save additional information while signing up the user.

Unfortunately, the column "isAdmin" is not generated on Database (as seen from Back4App Parse Dashboard).

How to assign additional column/attribute before signing up ?

Comment: can't you see the column even after refreshing the browser?

Comment: Oops, my bad. I didn't refresh it.